# Cannot remove item from shop cart in session

Tags: php, session, foreach

I have a shopping cart using PHP session.

to add an item:

```
$itemArray = array($produto=>
    array('id'=>$produto, 'titulo'=>$titulo, 'quantidade'=>$quantidade, 'preco'=>$preco, 'image'=>$img)
);

$_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
```

$produto is the ID (unique).

$itemArray looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [titulo] => Teste produto sem tamanho
            [quantidade] => 1
            [preco] => 1000.00
            [image] => /img/no_img.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [titulo] => Sapato masculino bonito e lustrado em couro
            [quantidade] => 2
            [preco] => 157.20
            [image] => produtos/1.jpg
        )

)
```

to remove:

```
if($action == "remove") {
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
        foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
            if($_GET["code"] == $k)
                unset($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]);              
            if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"]))
                unset($_SESSION["cart_item"]);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, sometimes it removes one product and others don't. If I have 2 products it doesnt remove any.
Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: `$k` is an index, `$v` is the value, are you sure your comparison should be by index, but not by value, i.e. `if($_GET["code"] == $v)`?

Comment: @mitkosoft using `== $v` it is not removing too.

Comment: what do you pass in `$_GET["code"]` that matches an element from `$itemArray` array?

Comment: @mitkosoft it is the product ID, eg: `cart.php?action=remove&code=1` the id from the product I want to remove.

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($itemArray)` result in your question?

Comment: Sure! @mitkosoft `array(2) { [0]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["titulo"]=> string(25) "Teste produto sem tamanho" ["quantidade"]=> int(1) ["preco"]=> string(7) "1000.00" ["image"]=> string(15) "/img/no_img.png" } [1]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["titulo"]=> string(43) "Sapato masculino bonito e lustrado em couro" ["quantidade"]=> int(2) ["preco"]=> string(6) "157.20" ["image"]=> string(14) "produtos/1.jpg" } }`

Comment: you have a multidimensional array, so if you need to unset entire SESSION element, you need to compare `if($_GET["code"] == $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]['id'])` or `if($_GET["code"] == $v['id'])`

Comment: No worries. I put that as an answer, please close the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a multidimensional array, so if you need to unset an entire `$_SESSION` element, you need to compare:

```
if($_GET["code"] == $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]['id'])
```

or

```
if($_GET["code"] == $v['id'])
```